# 2D numpy array doesn't implicitly convert from int64 to float64

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

How come when the numpy array is a vector, the setting works and the `dtype` is implicitly converted to float but when the numpy array is a matrix, the setting works but the `dtype` is still int. Here's a demo script to illustrate the problem.

```
import numpy as np

# successfully sets / converts
x = np.array([100, 101])
c = -np.max(x)
x += c
print 'before', x.dtype
x = np.exp(x)
print 'after', x.dtype

print x

# doesn't successfully set / convert
matrix = np.array([(100, 101), (102, 103)])
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    c = -np.max(matrix[i])
    matrix[i] += c
    print 'before', matrix[i].dtype
    matrix[i] = np.exp(matrix[i])
    print 'after', matrix[i].dtype

print matrix
```

output:

```
before int64
after float64 <-- from vector
[ 0.36787944  1.        ]
before int64
after int64 <-- from row 1 of matrix
before int64
after int64 <-- from row 2 of matrix
[[0 1]
 [0 1]]
```

The numbers are integer truncated, which was my original problem, traced down to this.

I'm using `Python 2.7.11` and `numpy 1.13.0`

Comment: Python and numpy version?

Comment: Python 2.7.11 and numpy 1.13.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you write a value into an existing array, the value is cast to match the array `dtype`. In your case, the resulting `float64` value is cast to `int64`:

```
b = numpy.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
b.dtype  # dtype('int64')
```

taking `numpy.exp()` of any of these values will return a `float64`:

```
numpy.exp(b[0, :]).dtype  # dtype('float64')
```

but if you now take this `float64` and write it back into the original `int64` array, it needs to be cast first:

```
b[0, :] = numpy.exp(b[0, :])
b.dtype  # dtype('int64')
```

Note that using

```
b = numpy.exp(b)
```

creates a new array with its own `dtype`. If instead you did

```
b[:] = numpy.exp(b[:])
```

you would be implicitly casting to `int64` again.

Also note that there is no need to write a loop like you did. Instead you can vectorize the operation:

```
np.exp(matrix - numpy.max(matrix, axis=1, keepdims=True))
# array([[ 0.36787944,  1.        ],
#        [ 0.36787944,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: How come the vector version works though? It's also originally an `int64` array but is automatically casted to `float64` by simply setting.

Comment: I have amended my answer to answer this.

Comment: Oh I see so `b` is set to a completely new array altogether whereas for a matrix, each row is written back into the original array.

Comment: Correct. Also note I have amended some simple code that solves your problem without a `for` loop.